# How to show the search box in Google Search results page?

Tags: google-search

I need to know the proper way to propagate the search-box in the **Google search result page**. I tried searching the Google for the procedure, but no luck. Any idea how to make appear the search-box ?

[image]

Comment: Curious, I have never actually seen that search box in the real? What did you search for and on what site did you search?

Comment: @w3d type www.nytimes.com in google and click search